# How to use a 3018 CNC Offline Controller in Marlin?

Tags: part-identification

I need to know what the name of this controller is in Marlin:

[image]

Surprisingly, I plugged it into AUX-2 on a MKS Gen L V1.0 with mostly default Marlin settings. It powers on and the buttons work. But whatever it is sending to the printerboard, the printerboard does not respond to. Also, it seems to block the connection to the computer when it is connected? SO maybe AUX-2 is the wrong port?

I unscrewed the case and tried to look for any markings on the PCB. There were none. I'm not sure what I should be looking for when I open it up.

I have bought a couple 3018 CNCs over the years and both have come with this controller, sold by different sellers.

[image]